# MobX Mutability vs Immutability

Tags: reactjs, immutability, mutable, mobx, mobx-react

Why MobX encourage mutable objects in their docs??

But, I see a tutorial about MobX: http://orlandohamsho.com/javascript/mobx-react-tutorial-building-first-application/

And, he used immutable approach in his tutorial instead of mutable one (see below).

`@action setUsers = (users) => { this.users = [...users];` (instead of pushing it)

I also think that immutablity approach is better (so that React.PureComponent can work which means optimizing performance)

Why MobX encourage to mutate object? What approach should I use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

it really depends on what you do. MobX doesn't use immutable concept, in fact, I don't think it's wise to immutable data in MobX. For example, if you add an item to an observable array, if you do it immutable way, the whole array will re-render. If you just simply push the item into the array, only the added item will render. There may be cases that you need to return a new array instead of mutating it, but in most cases, MobX should not use immutable way to update observable data.

Comment: Why would React re-render a component based only on 1 item in the array? Most of the time we map over arrays in the component, and the whole component is intended to be re-rendered. I don't see the practical point here.

Comment: If you have an array of 100 items to display, you change one item, you don't want to re-render all 100 items instead of just the updated one. That'll give you big performance improvement

Comment: It seems react handle this issue with the "key" prop now.  The all-rerender method only happend in prev versions of react

Comment: This also seems quite contrary to the current trend in development towards immutability which designed, in theory at least, to encourage better practices esp wrt multithreading/concurrency but also with complex interactions like app state replay, undo/redo, etc. Mobx does seem to disuade immutability but I don't see an rendering efficiency issues anymore than there is with Redux.